# Is there a way to match the installed VS2005 license with the serial number on the box?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, licensing

This is not a strictly programming question, but for developers working in teams might be a useful one. I bet someone already had similar problem.

We have several licenses for VS2005. I have one allotted to me, and the remaining ones are for my colleagues. I have just wiped my PC as a part of routine maintenance and now I am ready to install VS2005, but there are more than one box to choose from. Is there an easy way to find out *programmatically* (registry browsing / file look-up / etc.) which license (product key / serial number on the box) is installed on which PC?

Answer (score 1):

There's an application I've used in the past with MS Office and XP keys which looks like it's been updated to look for the key to any application. Free (!) download and information at the website, here: http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a shareware that can do this for me: http://www.product-key-explorer.com/. I was able to extract first 4 digits of the key, which was enough.